# Run youtube on webView crash sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube-api, uiwebviewdelegate

I build sample app that load youtube in webview, sometimes in specific videos the app is crash. 
This is the log:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background
>   thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This
>   will cause an exception in a future release.

I know that this is main thread issue when player start play the video, but not have solution, another thing that maybe can help to solve this, when this is happened, the webview delegate methud `-shouldStartLoadWithRequest` not called...

This is my `viewWillApear` :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    _ytWebView.delegate = self;
    _ytWebView.allowsLinkPreview = YES; 
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [_ytWebView loadRequest:request];

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Helper library for iOS developers looking to add YouTube video playback in their applications via the iframe player in a UIWebView https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

Answer (score 0):

Try running it on the main thread instead:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    _ytWebView.delegate = self;
    _ytWebView.allowsLinkPreview = YES; 
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [_ytWebView loadRequest:request];
});
}
```

Comment: I'll trying , but the main issue is that not every clicked on the you tube clips catch by the webview delegate , you have any idea ?

Comment: and this is still crash :  (

Comment: Hey wait, why are you calling this in `viewWillAppear`? That's where you're going wrong. Call it in `viewDidLoad`. With `dispatch_async`. I think it should work. I'll update my answer if you confirm this works.

Comment: The crash still happened

Comment: Did you load it in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Try `__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;` in your code and use it in `dispatch_async` block.

Comment: I dont understand where and when to use weakSelf parameter.